# Polyline encode gets wrong lat/lng after decoding

Tags: google-polyline

We are using Google's Polyline decoding algorithm to decode our coordinates. But in our case the most coordinates are wrong after decoding it. We have also tested the process with a deeper precision.

This is our code and also our logs to test that the coordinates are wrong:

```
let coordinates = [ [lat, lng], [...], ...];
console.log(coordinates[13347]); // Output: [ 13.44668, 52.47429 ]
let encoded = Polyline.encode(coordinates);
let decoded = Polyline.decode(encoded);
console.log(decoded[13347]); // Output: [ 13.44671, 52.47445 ]
console.log(coordinates.length == decoded.length)// true
```

In this case the distance is 20 meters which is a lot. Other points have distances like 150 meter or even more.

In my coordinates array are around 250.000 coordinates which we want to decode.

Am I missing something so the decode/encode process fails this hard ?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**
Add the following lines after the declaration of the `coordinates` variable:

```
coordinates = coordinates.map(
    pair => { return [pair[0].toFixed(5), pair[1].toFixed(5)]; }
);
```

---

**Full answer**

It looks like you're dealing with floating point rounding errors. Probably the library you use has incorrect implementation of the [Polyline encoding algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm).

In the description of the algorithm we read that the encoded string generated by the algorithm stores the differences between consecutive coordinates using fixed-precision numbers (with 5 decimal places). Therefore it is important to round the latitude and longitude to 5 decimal places **before** computing the differences. Without that step, the rounding errors may accumulate. In the worst case error may increase by about 0.000005 deg for each subsequent item in the encoded list.

The official implementation of the algorithm does not introduce accumulated rounding errors. However, the implementation found in NPM ([package polyline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyline)) gives incorrect results that indicate the invalid rounding of numbers.

Please look at the examples bellow:

### Example 1. Encoding a polyline using official implementation of the algorithm

(using `google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath` from the Google Maps JavaScript API)

```js
originalList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
    originalList.push(
        new google.maps.LatLng(6 * i / 1000000, 0)
    );
// originalList looks like: [[0.000000,0],[0.000006,0],[0.000012,0],[0.000018,0], ..., [0.000594,0]];
// (but with LatLng objects instead of 2-element arrays)

console.log(originalList[99].lat()) // 0.000594

var encodedList = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(originalList)
var decodedList = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedList)

console.log(decodedList[99].lat())  // 0.00059
```

#### Example 2. Encoding a polyline using [package polyline from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyline)

```js
let Polyline = require('polyline');

var originalList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
    originalList.push(
        [6 * i / 1000000, 0]
    );
// again: originalList == [[0.000000,0],[0.000006,0],[0.000012,0],[0.000018,0], ..., [0.000594,0]];

console.log(originalList[99][0]) // 0.000594

var encodedList = Polyline.encode(originalList);
var decodedList = Polyline.decode(encodedList);

console.log(decodedList[99][0])  // 0.00099
```

**Invalid result**: the values 0.000594 and 0.00099 differ by more than 0.000005.

### Possible fix

The library that you're using probably doesn't round the coordinates before computing the differences. 
For example when two consecutive points have latitudes `0.000000` and `0.000006`, the difference is `0.000006` and it is rounded to `0.00001` giving error of `0.000004`.
You may want to round the coordinates manually, before passing them to `Polyline.encode()`, eg. using the function `.toFixed(5)`:

```js
let Polyline = require('polyline');

var originalList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
    originalList.push(
        [(6 * i / 1000000).toFixed(5), 0]
    );
// before rounding: [[ 0.000000,0],[ 0.000006,0],[ 0.000012,0],[ 0.000018,0], ..., [ 0.000594,0]];
// after rounding:  [['0.00000',0],['0.00001',0],['0.00001',0],['0.00002',0], ..., ['0.00059',0]];

console.log(originalList[99][0]) // 0.00059

var encodedList = Polyline.encode(originalList);
var decodedList = Polyline.decode(encodedList);

console.log(decodedList[99][0])  // 0.00059
```

Comment: Thanks ged for this long answer. I will check out your examples ASAP and will tell you if some of them worked for us.

Comment: Rounding to 5 decimal places before encoding was the answer for me. It completely eliminated the cumulative errors when implementing this algorithm in C# with 100k+ data points.

Answer (score 1):

Polyline encoding is lossy:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm (`Polyline encoding is a *lossy* compression algorithm that allows you to store a series of coordinates as a single string`

How about using your own encoding scheme? The page above also shows the encoding scheme used by Google. Perhaps you can look for a trade-off between space and accuracy.

Comment: Of course the encoding is lossy - the coordinates are stored with precision up to 5 decimal places. But once the numbers get truncated, there should be no further data losses. The coordinates provided in question (before and after encoding) differ by more than 0.000005, this should not take place.

Comment: That is because consecutive points only retain offset from the earlier point. The cascaded effect can very well eat into first 5 decimal places. If the OP encodes each point separately, this should not happen.